# How do I put a border around my form using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a border around my checklist but I'm not sure how to write the CSS.. Currently the border is going around everything.. I've attached a screen shot to show you what I mean. The black border is what I'm getting and the red border I added in paint to show you what I'm trying to do.. Any help would be appreciated.

Image uploaded using imgbb.com

https://ibb.co/h6xTbK

My HTML for the left side "Subject list" and the center checklist

```
<div class="notes">
    <h2 class="subject">Subject Notes</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="htmlnotes.html">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="cssnotes.html">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="javanotes.html">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="rubynotes.html">Ruby</a></li>
            <li><a href="railsnotes.html">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
            <li><a href="jquerynotes.html">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>


<div class="checklist">
<h2>To Do List</h2>
<!-- To do list with check box as a test -->

        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
        </form>
</div>
```

My CSS for the left side "Subject notes" and the center checklist..

```
.notes ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.notes {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
}

.notes ul li {
    margin: 10px;

}

.notes li a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #493C3D;

}


.checklist {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You have done lots of mistake I have corrected it. Please check.

```css
.notes ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.notes {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 160px; */
  float: left;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.notes ul li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.notes li a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #493C3D;
}

.checklist {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="notes">
        <h2 class="subject">Subject Notes</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="htmlnotes.html">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="cssnotes.html">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="javanotes.html">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="rubynotes.html">Ruby</a></li>
            <li><a href="railsnotes.html">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
            <li><a href="jquerynotes.html">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="checklist">
        <h2>To Do List</h2>
        <!-- To do list with check box as a test -->

        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was after. Thanks for correcting my code.. I'm still learning CSS so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

I wrapped the checklist with a `div` , made its `position:inline-block` and then added a red border.

```css
.notes ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.notes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.notes ul li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.notes li a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #493C3D;
}

.checklist {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
.parent{
display:inline-block;
border:2px solid red;
padding:5px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="notes">
  <h2 class="subject">Subject Notes</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="htmlnotes.html">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="cssnotes.html">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="javanotes.html">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="rubynotes.html">Ruby</a></li>
    <li><a href="railsnotes.html">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
    <li><a href="jquerynotes.html">jQuery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="checklist">

  <!-- To do list with check box as a test -->

  <form>

    <div class="parent">
      <h2>To Do List</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="" />data<br>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add width to checklist:

```
<div class="notes">
    <h2 class="subject">Subject Notes</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="htmlnotes.html">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="cssnotes.html">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="javanotes.html">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="rubynotes.html">Ruby</a></li>
            <li><a href="railsnotes.html">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
            <li><a href="jquerynotes.html">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>


<div class="checklist">
<h2>To Do List</h2>
<!-- To do list with check box as a test -->

        <form>
          <div class="checklist_wrapper">
          <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="list" value="">data</input><br>
          </div>

        </form>
</div>

.notes ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.notes {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}

.notes ul li {
    margin: 10px;

}

.notes li a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #493C3D;

}


.checklist {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:40%;
}
```